# How can we get only text form the web page in a particular parent division using 'Nokogiri'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I am making a rails application, and I am supposed to work with `Nokogiri` for parsing the browser data. I could reach to get the data from, using css classes, and tags.

Now my question is that if we want to get the text data from a parent division in which there are 3 or 4 kinds of tags(p,span,sup,b..etc) again, then **how can we reach to get all tags data at a time in the parent division ?**

Can anybody help me please?

Comment: It's important to show the code you've written, and sample HTML containing the structures you're trying to navigate to get to the data you want. Without that information we're guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a parent division in which some types of tags like `p`, `u`, `b`, etc. are involved, write your code like:

```
 url="http://www.google.co.in"
 doc = Nokogiri::XML(open(url))
 your_required_text = doc.css('#main-head').text
```

Under the `#main-head` division all text will be returned.

I think the above will work for you.

Comment: Hello Mr.Gowri, thank you for your response. It is working now.